# CameraX and OpenGL to apply effects on real time Camera

Tags: java, android

I am dying from finding solutions for this. I am not a Java guy at all, I work with React Native most of the time, but now I need to create such a module in Java for my project. I will just pass the fragment shader code to the native side and render real-time effects on the camera view. This should be also recordable.

So, what I can understand, I need to apply OpenGL shade to each frame and render in a SurfaceView. In the old Camera class, there was a method `setPreviewTexture` but I can't see anything similar in the CameraX class.

I quite understand the process in theory, but a lack of knowledge in native Android development is not letting me code this.
Can anyone give me proper resources or code libraries that can help me to do this?

Comment: this could help: https://github.com/xizhang/camerax-gpuimage or if you do not want CameraX check this one out : https://github.com/cats-oss/android-gpuimage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally continued with [natario1/CameraView](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView/) library. This library is awesome, other than basic filters it is possible to write own filter using gl fragment shader. It has all features that a Camera should have.

I wrote my own native module with this to use in my react native. Highly recommended to check the library.